# QProcess causes memory leak

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qprocess

I'm building a C++/Qt5.1 app which uses QProcess to launch another program, then wait for the result.  Every time I run this code, valgrind says memory is lost on line 2 (the start line).

```
QProcess command(this);
command.start(commandpath, myParameters);
if (command.waitForStarted(waitToStart)) {
    command.write(myStdIn.toLatin1());
    command.closeWriteChannel();
    if (command.waitForFinished(waitToFinish)) {
        myStdOut = command.readAllStandardOutput();
        myStdErr = command.readAllStandardError();
    }
}
command.deleteLater();
```

I added the deletelater() line but it doesn't help.  (Note that the memory loss only occurs if the 'commandpath' program doesn't run successfully - for example, when I try to run a non-existant program).

Can someone explain why, and how to resolve this memory loss?

Here's some valgrind output if that helps:

```
16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 57 of 678
  in RunProcessWorker::run(RunProcessWorker::EMutex, QString, QString, QString, bool, QString, QStringList, QStringList, QString, QString&amp;, QString&amp;, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned long long&amp;, RunProcessWorker::EResultCodes&amp;, QProcess::ProcessError&amp;, int&amp;) in /mnt/lserver2/data/development/haast/src/systemcommands/runprocessworker.cpp:249
  1: operator new[](unsigned long) in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
  2: /opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.1.0
  3: QProcess::open(QFlags&lt;QIODevice::OpenModeFlag&gt;) in /opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.1.0
  4: QProcess::start(QString const&amp;, QStringList const&amp;, QFlags&lt;QIODevice::OpenModeFlag&gt;) in /opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.1.0
  5: RunProcessWorker::run(RunProcessWorker::EMutex, QString, QString, QString, bool, QString, QStringList, QStringList, QString, QString&amp;, QString&amp;, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned long long&amp;, RunProcessWorker::EResultCodes&amp;, QProcess::ProcessError&amp;, int&amp;) in <a href="file:///mnt/lserver2/data/development/haast/bin/debug/../../src/systemcommands/runprocessworker.cpp:249" >/mnt/lserver2/data/development/haast/src/systemcommands/runprocessworker.cpp:249</a>
```

Comment: And the memory is not released even when the `QProcess` object goes out of scope and is destructed?

Comment: No - after the method (containing the above code) goes out of scope, valgrind complains.  (This is running in a seperate thread - so I see the error while the program is still running)

Comment: Note, your `command` is not allocated with new, so doing `delete` with it would crash (here object goes out of scope and destructs before `deleteLater` takes effect, luckily).

Comment: I lack the Qt expertise to know for sure, could this bug be related?  (https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-33021)  Note the situation of lost memory only if program does not execute!

Comment: I upgraded to Qt Creator 5.3.1 (which should include a fix for this bug) but the bug still remains.  (I assume qt-creator bundles latest Qt libraries)

Comment: You actually installed Qt SDK, I assume. There's also stand-alone Qt Creator, which does not include any Qt version, just the IDE. Anyway, in Qt Creator options you should see which Qt versions it knows about. And then the Qt Creator project needs to have a kit for that version added.

Comment: For normal application development, easiest (even on Linux) is to use the online installer and use the Qt SDK installed under user home directory. It includes a maintenance tool which allows easy updating etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all findings by *valgrind* are "real" memory leaks, or leaks you should care about. As long as memory "leak" comes from a library, and does not grow even if you do the failing thing many times, then don't worry about it.

Even though it is considered bad practice in applications, libraries may allocate things from heap, which are never freed. The library *could* add an exit handler to release those, but it would slow down exit of program for no real gain, for resources which are released by the OS anyway in one big chunk.

For this reason, *valgrind* supports [suppressing errors](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress). Easiest way to do this with Qt is to [run valgrind under Qt Creator](https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator/creator-valgrind-overview.html), which has a correct suppression file for Qt libraries by default.

---

If you are worried that this is actually a Qt bug, then you should write code which does the leaky operation in a loop a million times. If size of leak increases, then it's bad, and you should probably [file a bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/) with the code to reproduce it. Even if it is a one-time leak in uncommon code path, having it fixed would probably be good, instead of leaving useless allocation to clutter the heap.

Comment: I'm too new at Qt - I don't want to create bug reports until I'm sure this isn't something stupid I'm doing.  I do run valgrind from Qt Creator directly...so I assume it's only showing me real memory leaks?!

Comment: Well, if valgrind complains even under Qt Creator, then *either* it is something that should be fixed in Qt libraries, *or* the suppression files Qt Creator uses should be updated to ignore it. So if you can write a short code which reproduces this, I would file a bug report with code and instructions to reproduce (maybe ask [at irc](http://qt-project.org/wiki/OnlineCommunities#fd7cfb00ff818bba4ce97ae5291ae16a) first about it).

Comment: I ran this 10 times in a row, and the memory leak only appears the first time start() is called.  Does that mean this is "OK"?  (is a little leak ok?  or am I misunderstanding what this means)

Comment: Well, first of all it *sounds like* a library problem, but one which should not cause your application any issues, so you don't need to worry about it. From Qt point of view, it should be investigated and *something* should be fixed, as said in the previous comment.